# This project is already on GitHub but there is no project on my account in GitHub

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I tried to delete ".git/config" file like this

```
[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = false
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
symlinks = false
ignorecase = true
[remote "github"]
url = https://github.com/nitol17/AustClassmanager.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/github/*
```

but same results. It again says that my project is already on GitHub

Comment: Did you run `git push`? I'm guessing you have committed but not pushed it to GitHub.

Comment: I tried this now. But i got error like this " Failed with error: fatal: repository 'https://github.com/nitol17/AustClassmanager.git/' not found"